# WatchOS 2 page-based dots over text/table

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos-2

Is there anyway this doesn't happen?

[image]

I have a label that adjusts to its content but if I put it inside a group I'm not allowed to scroll, or even if I put a table inside a group (the group not reaching the page dots) I can't scroll.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a spacing between the picture and the text so that the dots have black background. Look at the activity app how they do so the dots won't be in the way. However the dots seems to always be there if you have a page based app.

Answer (score 0):

WatchOS is still limited on its UI customisation. Your approach is correct but we just can provide so complex layouts yet (Table inside group with bottom margin). I'm sure WatchOS 3 will bring new additions.